# Pylint - how to skip invalid-name module error

Tags: python, pylint

How could I skip this error without changing the module name?

```
Module name AaB doesn't conform to snake_case naming style ('[^\\W\\dA-Z][^\\WA-Z]*$' pattern) (invalid-name)
```

I tried, at the beginning of the module

```
# pylint: disable-all
```

And

```
# pylint: disable=invalid-name
```

Also I tried to configure in the `.pylintrc` file:

```
ignore-patterns=AaB.py
```

What else could I try?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to the end of the line

```
# pylint: disable=C0103
```

Or, if you're using VSCode, try adding this to your settings.json

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--disable={c0103}"]
```

The snake_case naming style is opposite to the camel case naming style. The difference between them is what you use to replace a space, an underscore or an uppercase.

Take the name `button position` for example:

| snake_case | camel case |
| --- | --- |
| button_position | ButtonPosition |

[C1013](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:c0103) means that the name you're using doesn't fit the naming convention, which, in pylint, is the snake_case naming style. Using the camel case is acceptable, but the snake_case is more readable.

Comment: Thanks, but there is a reason for this name which I can't change and need to keep the convention to snake_case. 
Also i need the changes to pass CI, and I'm using PyCharm

Comment: In PyCharm, try open this:  `File > Settings> Tools > External Tools > pylint > Tool Settings`,  the set `Parameters `: ` --disable=C0103 $FilePath$` (see [this](https://blog.csdn.net/ITLearnHall/article/details/102539035) as a reference)

Comment: Also, the `#pylint disable` should be used like this :  `import AaB # pylint: disable=invalid-name` or `def AaB(...):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name`